# Report for user and assigned contacts (ACL)

Tags: civireport, acl, user-account, user

I have a set of users that have been assigned access to specific contacts (ACL based off a smart group for each user) - for each contact I have added a set of custom fields that a user needs to fill out (example call status) - The workflow is: the user signs in, has access to the contacts that has been assigned to him, calls up the contact and marks the contact custom fields appropriately

I am now looking to generate a report that shows all users and their corresponding contacts - I can't see any option to do so since I am unable to connect the user to assigned contacts

Is this possible to do through civiReports or would it need to be a database query?

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer directly, but I can make an alternate suggestion for your structure. Instead of using ACL on Groups, you could use our extension which builds ACLs off a Relationship.
This would require a Relationship between your "user" and the contacts they need to call, but it would mean that you can then use this to deliver Reports or Drupal Views to see who is connected to whom, and the status of their calls etc.
If it is of interest you can find it here https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls